# ImportXML not expanded as would overwrite data

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, flatten, google-query-language

[on this report](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DGAWyJ63A8QaDqyYp140S7UQz6_4iGFQSaK3118RVQU/edit?usp=sharing) I have an IMPORTXML function in Column B which is crawling a URL for the closing date specifically. URLS on column A

It mostly works fine, but on a couple of instance it will retrieve a #REF!, and the reason is stated as "Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in B58."
This is happening in Cell B57 currently

anyone know how I can fix this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `limit` like:

```
=QUERY(FLATTEN(IMPORTXML(A59, "//*[@id]")), 
 "where lower(Col1) starts with 'closing date' limit 1", )
```

Comment: Thank you!, however now seems to be creating a few #N/A errors saying it could not fetch the URL, don't suppose you would know why? Actually works perfectly now! thank you!!!

Comment: @LuisCarlosDosSantosSousa see pink cells: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EUNb-qrFYu5y0R7RkMoShm3BgCFh0FP4sQKvns3CckQ/edit#gid=30338061

Comment: Wow! thats unreal I cannot thank you enough!